# Can't store this regex in a variable

Tags: regex, bash

I am unable to store a particular regex in a variable in bash.

```
regex=".*(w1|w2|w3|w4).*"
echo $regex
```

Expected Output:

```
.*(w1|w2|w3|w4).*
```

Actual Output:

```
..
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Missing semicolon after the first line?  By the way, if you are using PHP, you should add that tag to your question.

Comment: Your code returns `.*(w1|w2|w3|w4).*` in Bash.

Comment: Your code seems Corect only. It return your expected output in shell

Answer (score 2):

It’s stored correctly. The issue is that you’re *using* the variable incorrectly: you *must* quote the variable, otherwise the result gets expanded by the shell, and interpreted as a shell glob.

So, use

```sh
echo "$regex"
```